# AnkhSVN Commits Are Very Slow

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ankhsvn, visualsvn-server

Recently, I had to move my SVN repositories to a different server, 
but I am experiencing some performance problems since the move.

I am using Visual Studio 2005, AnkhSVN 2.1.7819.411 and TortoiseSVN 1.6.6 on my workstation and VisualSVN Server on the server which runs Windows Server 2008.

Whenever I try to commit a file or view the file history in Visual Studio
it takes twenty odd seconds.

I confirmed that an exception has been made for VisualSVN Server on the server's firewall, but when I disable the server's firewall the performance is back to normal (1-2 seconds for a commit). When I do a commit or check the log on a file in TortoiseSVN the performance is fine as well.

To ensure that the problem was not related to the moving of the repositories, I am 
running these tests against a new repository which was created on the new server.

So, I reckon the problem lies with AnkhSVN, but am at a loss as how to diagnose it further.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That sound like an other problem with the firewall...btw. what about virus scanner (newly added or changed?)

Comment: There is no anti-virus installed on the server. It would appear that the problem lies between Ankh and the firewall since Tortoise doesn't present with the same problem.

Comment: what happens when you use a command-line client? You can get one at http://www.sliksvn.com/en/download/

Comment: It exhibits exactly the same behaviour as Ankh. Takes about twenty odd seconds for a commit with the server's firewall enabled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which hostname do you use to connect to your server?

Does that hostname resolve to an IPv6 and a IPv4 address? (http://localhost does that on Windows Vista and later).

The Subversion used by AnkhSVN (SharpSvn) is IPv6 enabled, so it will try IPv6 before IPv4 if a host resolves to both address types.

You can try if this is an issue by starting a

```
ping <hostname>
```

on a command prompt. If the host is IPv6 enabled you should see IPv6 addresses there. And if not, just the normal IPv4 addresses.

If you use **https://** to connect to your host, then you might see a **different** issue:
If AnkhSVN uses neon 0.29.0-.0.29.2 3 (See Help->About), neon has a performance regression since earlier versions that are still used by some of the other clients.

Neon 0.29.0-0.29.2 try to close https connections in a different way that causes slowdowns if you use a proxy or a non apache server that handles connection closes in a different way. This issue was resolved in neon 0.29.3, which is available in later AnkhSVN versions.

Comment: The hostname resolves to a IPv6 address. I do use https://, but AnkhSVN's Help->About states that SharpSVN is linked to, among other things, neon 029.3.

Comment: @jakdep: (updated answer for other readers). If your hostname resolves to an ipv6 address, you should make sure that the services you host using that hostname also use ipv6. (So you should enable IPv6 in your VisualSVN server if that is possible)

Or you should create a different DNS alias that only uses IPv4 for IPv4 only services. (Most likely you see the same slowdown if you use a webbrowser to connect to that url as most of them are IPv6 enabled these days)

Comment: First off, thanks for taking the time to try to help me out. :)
Your right as far as the webbrowsers are concerned they also have an delay when initially listing the repositories. How do I enabled IPv6 on VisualSVN Server?

Comment: Woah! Thanks! Disabling IPV6 made my commits from AnkhSVN to Subversion Edge server lightning fast!

Answer (score 4):

I had this exact same problem.  Thanks Bert for pointing me in the right direction!  But it bears repeating here, because I don't think Bert really spelled it out in his answer:

Solution: If your machine is resolving your AnkhSVN host using IP6, create an IP4 alias for it in your hosts file.

Comment: Yes, I took a look at the problem again after I saw your answer and working through IPv4 removed the delay.

Answer (score 2):

On my internal server running Windows 7. I simply disabled IPv6 and it worked perfectly. No delay when committing. Here's detailed instructions

1) right click network icon tray
2) open network sharing
3) Under View your active networks subsection, click "Connections: Local Area Connection" link (default name). It will bring up connection properties window.
4) Click Properties button.
5) Uncheck IPv6. Click Ok.

Ps, love Ankh. For anyone not sure, this integrates wonderfully into Visual Studio, and is better than VisualSVN. my 2 cents.

Comment: Yes, of course, why didn't I think of that? Thanks for your input. Yes, when I compared Ankh and VisualSVN Ankh's intergration was much better.