# How can I speed up Subversion checkins? (Using ANKH, latest, Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: svn, performance, ankhsvn

I've started working on a new web project with some friends... we are using the latest Subversion server (installed last week), the latest version of ANKH.

My web project is a whapping 1.5 megabytes (that's with all images, css files, dll's after compiling, pdb files... etc).

Checking in even super small changes (literally adding the letter "x" to a few files for testing)... takes FOREVER! (about 10 seconds - I almost killed myself).

The ANKH client is measuring in **BYTES PER SECOND** ... BYTES? per second... I must be doing something wrong. Does anyone what config file has a joke *totallyMessWithPeople=true* so that I can turn that off or something?

Oh, also, changing one "big" file of a super 10k gains speed up to nearly the speed of light (which is apparently 857 bytes per second).

Help me obi wan kenobi, you're my only hope!

EDIT: `As a note... my real work project that uses Visual Source Safe 2005 (I know, ouch) uploads files at about 200-500kbps from this very same computer/internet connection.`

Comment: Same issue here - I have SVN installed directly on a personal development machine (though storage is on a NAS device) and find it VERY slow as well.  At the office, we use wush.net and that seems MUCH faster.

Comment: Generally its not the size of the files but number of the files that really slows down svn check-out process. if you are using https that slows down also. There is this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2681241/ankhsvn-commits-are-very-slow so I guess IP4/IP6 conflict maybe a great slow down also. I use AnkhSVN myself for WinForms project I work on now ~3 megabtytes and it is very fast.

Comment: You really didn't provide a lot of useful information.  Which protocol are you using to commit to the repository?  If you commit locally vs remotely what is the speed difference?  If you choose a different protocol, what is the speed difference?  If you commit in the command line client vs ANKH SVN, is there a difference? What if you run Process Monitor on client do you see anything interesting there?  What about on server?  Do you have any commit hook scripts?  Did you turn the `useFastConnection` config flag on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier I said that I exported the cert and imported it as a "trusted root cert" and then my speed problems went away. That was true, but that's not the *reason* why my speed problems went away.

It turns out that I was just VPN'd into work, and so it was going slower. So, in my case, just disconnecting from my VPN increased my speed (obviously).

I just wanted to make this post so that people aren't lead astray by my earlier one.

Answer (score 3):

Note that when you use http:// or https:// the numbers AnkhSVN (and all other Subversion clients) show are not the real data transferred.

The neon library doesn't provide an actual bytecount, but just some indication on how far the contents is transferred, while some of the data is actually transfered in the headers. (The serf and svn layers provide better information). If you want to tell what the actual amount of data transfered is you need a separate tool.

When you just start a Subversion operation a lot of time is spend in opening a server session, especially on low latency links. (For AnkhSVN's development, I use a repository in California from the Netherlands). Subversion 1.7 will improve this handshake phase with it's new 'HTTPv2' handshake. (The v2 tells that Subversion uses different HTTP requests; it is still HTTP/1.1 on the line).

But there can be different reasons that subversion clients are slow (see the comments on your question): IPv4 vs IPv6 is a common reason, and a few releases ago the neon version used by AnkhSVN had a peformance regression on disconnecting from some https servers.